# SQL Server Stored Procedure Update not working with ASP.Net C# GridView RowUpdating

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview, stored-procedures

I am having an issue but I am not getting any errors thrown. What's happening is that I have a stored procedure that is driving my update but I am unable to get the gridview to update.

I hit the `Update` link button but it doesn't actually update the record.

Here is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CompDev_Update](
@CompID int,
@NewDevCount nchar(10) = null,
@DevelopmentName nvarchar(255) = null,
@City nvarchar(255) = null,
@State nvarchar(255) = null,
@ZipCodeofNewDev nchar(10) = null,
@ProjectStatus nvarchar(255) = null,
@ShoppingCenter nvarchar(255) = null,
@ProjectStartDate float = null,
@ProjectDescription nvarchar(255) = null,
@ProposedAnchorTenants nvarchar(255) = null,
@GLA nchar(10) = null,
@EstCompDate float = null,
@Developer nvarchar(255) = null,
@BusinessUnit nchar(10) = null,
@BU nchar(10) = null,
@CenterName nvarchar(255) = null,
@MSA nvarchar(255) = null,
@BrixmorMSARank nchar(10) = null,
@Count nchar(10) = null,
@Region nvarchar(255) = null,
@DistancefromNewDev nchar(10) = null
)
   AS
   BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
UPDATE WestCompetition Set NewDevCount=@NewDevCount, DevelopmentName=@DevelopmentName,
    City=@City, [State]=@State, ZipCodeofNewDev=@ZipCodeofNewDev, ProjectStatus=@ProjectStatus,
    ShoppingCenter=@ShoppingCenter, ProjectStartDate=@ProjectStartDate, ProjectDescription=@ProjectDescription,
    ProposedAnchorTenants=@ProposedAnchorTenants, GLA=@GLA, EstCompDate=@EstCompDate,
    Developer=@Developer, BusinessUnit=@BusinessUnit, BU=@BU, CenterName=@CenterName,
    MSA=@MSA, BrixmorMSARank=@BrixmorMSARank, [Count]=@Count, Region=@Region,
    DistancefromNewDev=@DistancefromNewDev
    WHERE CompID = @CompID
```

END

Here is my asp.net c# behind code:

```
 protected void gvCompetition_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        Label CompID = (Label)gvCompetition.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lblCompID");
        TextBox NewDevCount = (TextBox)gvCompetition.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtNewDevCount");
        TextBox DevelopmentName = (TextBox)gvCompetition.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtDevelopmentName");
        TextBox City = (TextBox)gvCompetition.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtCity");
        TextBox State = (TextBox)gvCompetition.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtState");
        TextBox ZipCodeofNewDev = (TextBox)gvCompetition.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtZipCode");
        TextBox ProjectStatus = (TextBox)gvCompetition.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtProjectStatus");
        TextBox ShoppingCenter = (TextBox)gvCompetition.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtShoppingCenter");
        TextBox ProjectStartDate = (TextBox)gvCompetition.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtProjectStartDate");
        TextBox ProjectDescription = (TextBox)gvCompetition.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtProjectDescription");
        TextBox ProposedAnchorTenants = (TextBox)gvCompetition.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtProposedAnchorTenants");
        TextBox GLA = (TextBox)gvCompetition.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtGLA");
        TextBox EstCompDate = (TextBox)gvCompetition.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEstCompDate");
        TextBox Developer = (TextBox)gvCompetition.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtDeveloper");
        TextBox BusinessUnit = (TextBox)gvCompetition.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtBusinessUnit");
        TextBox BU = (TextBox)gvCompetition.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtBU");
        TextBox CenterName = (TextBox)gvCompetition.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtCenterName");
        TextBox MSA = (TextBox)gvCompetition.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtMSA");
        TextBox BrixmorMSARank = (TextBox)gvCompetition.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtBrixmorMSARank");
        TextBox Count = (TextBox)gvCompetition.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtCount");
        TextBox Region = (TextBox)gvCompetition.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtRegion");
        TextBox DistancefromNewDev = (TextBox)gvCompetition.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtDistancefromNewDev");
        string ecompid = CompID.Text;
        string enewdevcount = NewDevCount.Text;
        string edevelopmentname = DevelopmentName.Text;
        string ecity = City.Text;
        string estate = State.Text;
        string ezipcode = ZipCodeofNewDev.Text;
        string eprojectstatus = ProjectStatus.Text;
        string eshoppingcenter = ShoppingCenter.Text;
        string eprojectstartdate = ProjectStartDate.Text;
        string eprojectdescription = ProjectDescription.Text;
        string eproposedanchor = ProposedAnchorTenants.Text;
        string egla = GLA.Text;
        string eestcompdate = EstCompDate.Text;
        string edeveloper = Developer.Text;
        string ebusinessunit = BusinessUnit.Text;
        string ebu = BU.Text;
        string ecentername = CenterName.Text;
        string emsa = MSA.Text;
        string ebrixmormsarank = BrixmorMSARank.Text;
        string ecount = Count.Text;
        string eregion = Region.Text;
        string edistancefromnewdev = DistancefromNewDev.Text;

        UpdateCompetition(ecompid, enewdevcount, edevelopmentname, ecity, estate, ezipcode, eprojectstatus, eshoppingcenter, eprojectstartdate, eprojectdescription, eproposedanchor,
            egla, eestcompdate, edeveloper, ebusinessunit, ebu, ecentername, emsa, ebrixmormsarank, ecount, eregion, edistancefromnewdev);

        gvCompetition.EditIndex = -1;
        BindCompetition();
    }

    protected void UpdateCompetition(string compid, string newdevcount, string developmentname, string city, string state, string zipcode,
        string projectstatus, string shoppingcenter, string projectstartdate, string projectdescription, string proposedanchor, string gla,
        string estcompdate, string developer, string businessunit, string bu, string centername, string msa, string brixmormsarank,
        string count, string region, string distancefromnewdev)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cnnString);
        conn.Open();
        command = new SqlCommand();
        command.Connection = conn;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.CommandText = "CompDev_Update";

        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CompID", SqlDbType.Int));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@NewDevCount", SqlDbType.NChar, 10));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DevelopmentName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@City", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@State", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ZipCodeofNewDev", SqlDbType.NChar, 10));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ProjectStatus", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ShoppingCenter", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ProjectStartDate", SqlDbType.Float));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ProjectDescription", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ProposedAnchorTenants", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@GLA", SqlDbType.NChar, 10));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EstCompDate", SqlDbType.Float));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Developer", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@BusinessUnit", SqlDbType.NChar, 10));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@BU", SqlDbType.NChar, 10));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CenterName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MSA", SqlDbType.NChar, 10));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@BrixmorMSARank", SqlDbType.NChar, 10));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Count", SqlDbType.NChar, 10));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Region", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DistancefromNewDev", SqlDbType.NChar, 10));

        command.Parameters["@CompID"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(compid.ToString());
        command.Parameters["@NewDevCount"].Value = newdevcount;
        command.Parameters["@DevelopmentName"].Value = developmentname;
        command.Parameters["@City"].Value = city;
        command.Parameters["@State"].Value = state;
        command.Parameters["@ZipCodeofNewDev"].Value = zipcode;
        command.Parameters["@ProjectStatus"].Value = projectstatus;
        command.Parameters["@ShoppingCenter"].Value = shoppingcenter;
        command.Parameters["@ProjectStartDate"].Value = projectstartdate;
        command.Parameters["@ProjectDescription"].Value = projectdescription;
        command.Parameters["@ProposedAnchorTenants"].Value = proposedanchor;
        command.Parameters["@GLA"].Value = gla;
        command.Parameters["@EstCompDate"].Value = estcompdate;
        command.Parameters["@Developer"].Value = developer;
        command.Parameters["@BusinessUnit"].Value = businessunit;
        command.Parameters["@BU"].Value = bu;
        command.Parameters["@CenterName"].Value = centername;
        command.Parameters["@MSA"].Value = msa;
        command.Parameters["@BrixmorMSARank"].Value = brixmormsarank;
        command.Parameters["@Count"].Value = count;
        command.Parameters["@Region"].Value = region;
        command.Parameters["@DistancefromNewDev"].Value = distancefromnewdev;

        da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);

        conn.Close();
    }
```

Here is my asp.net code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:GridView ID="gvCompetition" OnPageIndexChanging="gvCompetition_PageIndexChanging" 
                OnRowEditing="gvCompetition_RowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="gvCompetition_RowCancelingEdit"
                OnRowUpdating="gvCompetition_RowUpdating"
                runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" 
                BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="1" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" 
                AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Font-Size="10px">
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#7a1501" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#ed2d22" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="#f68121" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FBFBF2" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#848384" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#EAEAD3" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#575357" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:templatefield Headertext="ID">
                        <itemtemplate>
                            <asp:label ID="lblCompID" runat="server" text='<%#Eval("CompID") %>'></asp:label>
                        </itemtemplate>
                    </asp:templatefield>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="New Dev Count">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblNewDevCount" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("NewDevCount") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewDevCount" Width="100%" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("NewDevCount") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Development Name">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblDevelopmentName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("DevelopmentName") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDevelopmentName" Width="100%" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("DevelopmentName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="City">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblCity" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("City") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" Width="100%" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("City") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="State">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblState" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("State") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtState" Width="100%" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("State") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Zip Code">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblZipCode" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ZipCodeofNewDev") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtZipCode" Width="100%" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ZipCodeofNewDev") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Project Status">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblProjectStatus" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ProjectStatus") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtProjectStatus" Width="100%" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ProjectStatus") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Shopping Center">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblShoppingCenter" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ShoppingCenter") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtShoppingCenter" Width="100%" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ShoppingCenter") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Project Start Date">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblProjectStartDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ProjectStartDate") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtProjectStartDate" Width="100%" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ProjectStartDate") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Project Description">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblProjectDescription" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ProjectDescription") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtProjectDescription" Width="100%" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ProjectDescription") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Proposed Anchor Tenants">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblProposedAnchorTenants" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ProposedAnchorTenants") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtProposedAnchorTenants" Width="100%" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ProposedAnchorTenants") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="GLA">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblGLA" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("GLA") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtGLA" Width="100%" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("GLA") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Est. Completion Date">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblEstCompDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("EstCompDate") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEstCompDate" Width="100%" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("EstCompDate") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Developer">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblDeveloper" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Developer") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDeveloper" Width="100%" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Developer") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Business Unit">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblBusinessUnit" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("BusinessUnit") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtBusinessUnit" Width="100%" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("BusinessUnit") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="BU">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblBU" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("BU") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtBU" Width="100%" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("BU") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CenterName">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblCenterName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("CenterName") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCenterName" Width="100%" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("CenterName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MSA">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblMSA" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("MSA") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtMSA" Width="100%" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("MSA") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Brixmor MSA Rank">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblBrixmorMSARank" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("BrixmorMSARank") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtBrixmorMSARank" Width="100%" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("BrixmorMSARank") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Count">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblCount" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Count") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCount" Width="100%" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Count") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Region">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblRegion" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Region") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtRegion" Width="100%" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Region") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Distance from New Dev">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblDistancefromNewDev" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("DistancefromNewDev") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDistancefromNewDev" Width="100%" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("DistancefromNewDev") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>


                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnEdit" Text="EDIT" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" />

                            <span onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record')">
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" Text="DELETE" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" />
                            </span>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnUpdate" Text="UPDATE" runat="server" CommandName="Update" />
                            <br />
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnCancel" Text="CANCEL" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="gvCompetition" EventName="PageIndexChanging" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="gvCompetition" EventName="RowEditing" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="gvCompetition" EventName="RowUpdating" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="gvCompetition" EventName="RowCancelingEdit" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

What am I doing wrong that the update will not happen? And why am I not getting any errors thrown when it does not update?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Also, I find those "do-it-all" stored procedure - while tempting - very dangerous in the end. You have one single messy procedure, you need to change it every time anything changes .... why not just have **four** separate, focussed procedures - one to `SELECT`, one to `INSERT`, one to `UPDATE` and a last one to `DELETE` (if that's even needed). Think about the **Single Responsibility Principle** - every piece of code should do **one thing well, and one thing only**. Right now, you're passing in **way too many parameters** just to delete something ....

Comment: Ok, I separated out my stored procedures but the Update is still not working on Gridview.  My stored procedure is now called CompDev_Update and all I changed was this ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CompDev_Update](
 @CompID int,                                                       My Update query is still the same.  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stored Procedures:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CompDev_Select]
AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        SELECT  [WC].[CompID]
              , [WC].[NewDevCount]
              , [WC].[DevelopmentName]
              , [WC].[City]
              , [WC].[State]
              , [WC].[ZipCodeofNewDev]
              , [WC].[ProjectStatus]
              , [WC].[ShoppingCenter]
              , [WC].[ProjectStartDate]
              , [WC].[ProjectDescription]
              , [WC].[ProposedAnchorTenants]
              , [WC].[GLA]
              , [WC].[EstCompDate]
              , [WC].[Developer]
              , [WC].[BusinessUnit]
              , [WC].[BU]
              , [WC].[CenterName]
              , [WC].[MSA]
              , [WC].[BrixmorMSARank]
              , [WC].[Count]
              , [WC].[Region]
              , [WC].[DistancefromNewDev]
        FROM    [dbo].[WestCompetition] AS WC

        SET NOCOUNT OFF;
    END
GO



ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CompDev_Update]
    ( @CompID INT
    , @NewDevCount NCHAR(10) = NULL
    , @DevelopmentName NVARCHAR(255) = NULL
    , @City NVARCHAR(255) = NULL
    , @State NVARCHAR(255) = NULL
    , @ZipCodeofNewDev NCHAR(10) = NULL
    , @ProjectStatus NVARCHAR(255) = NULL
    , @ShoppingCenter NVARCHAR(255) = NULL
    , @ProjectStartDate FLOAT = NULL
    , @ProjectDescription NVARCHAR(255) = NULL
    , @ProposedAnchorTenants NVARCHAR(255) = NULL
    , @GLA NCHAR(10) = NULL
    , @EstCompDate FLOAT = NULL
    , @Developer NVARCHAR(255) = NULL
    , @BusinessUnit NCHAR(10) = NULL
    , @BU NCHAR(10) = NULL
    , @CenterName NVARCHAR(255) = NULL
    , @MSA NVARCHAR(255) = NULL
    , @BrixmorMSARank NCHAR(10) = NULL
    , @Count NCHAR(10) = NULL
    , @Region NVARCHAR(255) = NULL
    , @DistancefromNewDev NCHAR(10) = NULL )
AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        UPDATE  WC
        SET     NewDevCount = @NewDevCount
              , DevelopmentName = @DevelopmentName
              , City = @City
              , [State] = @State
              , ZipCodeofNewDev = @ZipCodeofNewDev
              , ProjectStatus = @ProjectStatus
              , ShoppingCenter = @ShoppingCenter
              , ProjectStartDate = @ProjectStartDate
              , ProjectDescription = @ProjectDescription
              , ProposedAnchorTenants = @ProposedAnchorTenants
              , GLA = @GLA
              , EstCompDate = @EstCompDate
              , Developer = @Developer
              , BusinessUnit = @BusinessUnit
              , BU = @BU
              , CenterName = @CenterName
              , MSA = @MSA
              , BrixmorMSARank = @BrixmorMSARank
              , [Count] = @Count
              , Region = @Region
              , DistancefromNewDev = @DistancefromNewDev
        FROM    [dbo].[WestCompetition] AS WC
        WHERE   ( [WC].CompID = @CompID );

        SET NOCOUNT OFF;
    END
GO


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CompDev_Insert]
    ( @NewDevCount NCHAR(10) = NULL
    , @DevelopmentName NVARCHAR(255) = NULL
    , @City NVARCHAR(255) = NULL
    , @State NVARCHAR(255) = NULL
    , @ZipCodeofNewDev NCHAR(10) = NULL
    , @ProjectStatus NVARCHAR(255) = NULL
    , @ShoppingCenter NVARCHAR(255) = NULL
    , @ProjectStartDate FLOAT = NULL
    , @ProjectDescription NVARCHAR(255) = NULL
    , @ProposedAnchorTenants NVARCHAR(255) = NULL
    , @GLA NCHAR(10) = NULL
    , @EstCompDate FLOAT = NULL
    , @Developer NVARCHAR(255) = NULL
    , @BusinessUnit NCHAR(10) = NULL
    , @BU NCHAR(10) = NULL
    , @CenterName NVARCHAR(255) = NULL
    , @MSA NVARCHAR(255) = NULL
    , @BrixmorMSARank NCHAR(10) = NULL
    , @Count NCHAR(10) = NULL
    , @Region NVARCHAR(255) = NULL
    , @DistancefromNewDev NCHAR(10) = NULL )
AS
    INSERT  INTO [dbo].[WestCompetition]
            ( [NewDevCount]
            , [DevelopmentName]
            , [City]
            , [State]
            , [ZipCodeofNewDev]
            , [ProjectStatus]
            , [ShoppingCenter]
            , [ProjectStartDate]
            , [ProjectDescription]
            , [ProposedAnchorTenants]
            , [GLA]
            , [EstCompDate]
            , [Developer]
            , [BusinessUnit]
            , [BU]
            , [CenterName]
            , [MSA]
            , [BrixmorMSARank]
            , [Count]
            , [Region]
            , [DistancefromNewDev] )
    VALUES  ( @NewDevCount
            , @DevelopmentName
            , @City
            , @State
            , @ZipCodeofNewDev
            , @ProjectStatus
            , @ShoppingCenter
            , @ProjectStartDate
            , @ProjectDescription
            , @ProposedAnchorTenants
            , @GLA
            , @EstCompDate
            , @Developer
            , @BusinessUnit
            , @BU
            , @CenterName
            , @MSA
            , @BrixmorMSARank
            , @Count
            , @Region
            , @DistancefromNewDev );
GO


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CompDev_Delete] ( @CompID INT )
AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        DELETE  WC
        FROM    [dbo].[WestCompetition] AS WC
        WHERE   [WC].[CompID] = @CompID

        SET NOCOUNT OFF;
    END
GO
```

Front-end Code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <div>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="CompID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" InsertItemPosition="LastItem">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <tr style="background-color: rgba(246, 129, 33, 1); border: 1px solid rgba(153, 153, 153, 1);">
                                <td><asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" /></td>
                                <td><asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" /></td>
                                <td><asp:Label ID="CompIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CompID") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:Label ID="NewDevCountLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("NewDevCount") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:Label ID="DevelopmentNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DevelopmentName") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:Label ID="CityLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("City") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:Label ID="StateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("State") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:Label ID="ZipCodeofNewDevLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ZipCodeofNewDev") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:Label ID="ProjectStatusLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProjectStatus") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:Label ID="ShoppingCenterLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ShoppingCenter") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:Label ID="ProjectStartDateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProjectStartDate") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:Label ID="ProjectDescriptionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProjectDescription") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:Label ID="ProposedAnchorTenantsLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProposedAnchorTenants") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:Label ID="GLALabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("GLA") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:Label ID="EstCompDateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EstCompDate") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:Label ID="DeveloperLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Developer") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:Label ID="BusinessUnitLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("BusinessUnit") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:Label ID="BULabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("BU") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:Label ID="CenterNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CenterName") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:Label ID="MSALabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MSA") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:Label ID="BrixmorMSARankLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("BrixmorMSARank") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:Label ID="CountLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Count") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:Label ID="RegionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Region") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:Label ID="DistancefromNewDevLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DistancefromNewDev") %>' /></td>
                            </tr>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                            <tr style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);">
                                <td><asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" /></td>
                                <td><asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" /></td>
                                <td><asp:Label ID="CompIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CompID") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:Label ID="NewDevCountLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("NewDevCount") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:Label ID="DevelopmentNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DevelopmentName") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:Label ID="CityLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("City") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:Label ID="StateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("State") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:Label ID="ZipCodeofNewDevLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ZipCodeofNewDev") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:Label ID="ProjectStatusLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProjectStatus") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:Label ID="ShoppingCenterLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ShoppingCenter") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:Label ID="ProjectStartDateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProjectStartDate") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:Label ID="ProjectDescriptionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProjectDescription") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:Label ID="ProposedAnchorTenantsLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProposedAnchorTenants") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:Label ID="GLALabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("GLA") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:Label ID="EstCompDateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EstCompDate") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:Label ID="DeveloperLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Developer") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:Label ID="BusinessUnitLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("BusinessUnit") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:Label ID="BULabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("BU") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:Label ID="CenterNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CenterName") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:Label ID="MSALabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MSA") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:Label ID="BrixmorMSARankLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("BrixmorMSARank") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:Label ID="CountLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Count") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:Label ID="RegionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Region") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:Label ID="DistancefromNewDevLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DistancefromNewDev") %>' /></td>
                            </tr>
                        </AlternatingItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <tr>
                                <td><asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" /></td>
                                <td><asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" /></td>
                                <td><asp:Label ID="CompIDLabel1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CompID") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:TextBox ID="NewDevCountTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("NewDevCount") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:TextBox ID="DevelopmentNameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DevelopmentName") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:TextBox ID="CityTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("City") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:TextBox ID="StateTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("State") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:TextBox ID="ZipCodeofNewDevTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ZipCodeofNewDev") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:TextBox ID="ProjectStatusTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProjectStatus") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:TextBox ID="ShoppingCenterTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ShoppingCenter") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:TextBox ID="ProjectStartDateTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProjectStartDate") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:TextBox ID="ProjectDescriptionTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProjectDescription") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:TextBox ID="ProposedAnchorTenantsTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProposedAnchorTenants") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:TextBox ID="GLATextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("GLA") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:TextBox ID="EstCompDateTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("EstCompDate") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:TextBox ID="DeveloperTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Developer") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:TextBox ID="BusinessUnitTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BusinessUnit") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:TextBox ID="BUTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BU") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:TextBox ID="CenterNameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CenterName") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:TextBox ID="MSATextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MSA") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:TextBox ID="BrixmorMSARankTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BrixmorMSARank") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:TextBox ID="CountTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Count") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:TextBox ID="RegionTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Region") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:TextBox ID="DistancefromNewDevTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DistancefromNewDev") %>' /></td>
                            </tr>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <EmptyDataTemplate>
                            <table runat="server" style="">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>No data was returned.</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </EmptyDataTemplate>
                        <InsertItemTemplate>
                            <tr style="">
                                <td><asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" /></td>
                                <td><asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Clear" /></td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td><asp:TextBox ID="NewDevCountTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("NewDevCount") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:TextBox ID="DevelopmentNameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DevelopmentName") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:TextBox ID="CityTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("City") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:TextBox ID="StateTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("State") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:TextBox ID="ZipCodeofNewDevTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ZipCodeofNewDev") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:TextBox ID="ProjectStatusTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProjectStatus") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:TextBox ID="ShoppingCenterTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ShoppingCenter") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:TextBox ID="ProjectStartDateTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProjectStartDate") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:TextBox ID="ProjectDescriptionTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProjectDescription") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:TextBox ID="ProposedAnchorTenantsTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProposedAnchorTenants") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:TextBox ID="GLATextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("GLA") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:TextBox ID="EstCompDateTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("EstCompDate") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:TextBox ID="DeveloperTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Developer") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:TextBox ID="BusinessUnitTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BusinessUnit") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:TextBox ID="BUTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BU") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:TextBox ID="CenterNameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CenterName") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:TextBox ID="MSATextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MSA") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:TextBox ID="BrixmorMSARankTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BrixmorMSARank") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:TextBox ID="CountTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Count") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:TextBox ID="RegionTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Region") %>' /></td>
                                <td><asp:TextBox ID="DistancefromNewDevTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DistancefromNewDev") %>' /></td>
                            </tr>
                        </InsertItemTemplate>
                        <LayoutTemplate>
                            <table runat="server">
                                <tr runat="server">
                                    <td runat="server">
                                        <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" style="">
                                            <tr runat="server" style="background-color: rgba(122, 21, 1, 1); font-weight: bold; color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);">
                                                <th runat="server"></th>
                                                <th runat="server"></th>
                                                <th runat="server"><asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkButton1" style="color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);" Text="CompID" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="CompID" /></th>
                                                <th runat="server"><asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkButton2" style="color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);" Text="NewDevCount" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="NewDevCount" /></th>
                                                <th runat="server"><asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkButton3" style="color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);" Text="DevelopmentName" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="DevelopmentName" /></th>
                                                <th runat="server"><asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkButton4" style="color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);" Text="City" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="City" /></th>
                                                <th runat="server"><asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkButton5" style="color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);" Text="State" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="State" /></th>
                                                <th runat="server"><asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkButton6" style="color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);" Text="ZipCodeofNewDev" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="ZipCodeofNewDev" /></th>
                                                <th runat="server"><asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkButton7" style="color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);" Text="ProjectStatus" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="ProjectStatus" /></th>
                                                <th runat="server"><asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkButton8" style="color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);" Text="ShoppingCenter" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="ShoppingCenter" /></th>
                                                <th runat="server"><asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkButton9" style="color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);" Text="ProjectStartDate" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="ProjectStartDate" /></th>
                                                <th runat="server"><asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkButton10" style="color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);" Text="ProjectDescription" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="ProjectDescription" /></th>
                                                <th runat="server"><asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkButton11" style="color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);" Text="ProposedAnchorTenants" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="ProposedAnchorTenants" /></th>
                                                <th runat="server"><asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkButton12" style="color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);" Text="GLA" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="GLA" /></th>
                                                <th runat="server"><asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkButton13" style="color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);" Text="EstCompDate" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="EstCompDate" /></th>
                                                <th runat="server"><asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkButton14" style="color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);" Text="Developer" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="Developer" /></th>
                                                <th runat="server"><asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkButton15" style="color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);" Text="BusinessUnit" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="BusinessUnit" /></th>
                                                <th runat="server"><asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkButton16" style="color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);" Text="BU" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="BU" /></th>
                                                <th runat="server"><asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkButton17" style="color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);" Text="CenterName" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="CenterName" /></th>
                                                <th runat="server"><asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkButton18" style="color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);" Text="MSA" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="MSA" /></th>
                                                <th runat="server"><asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkButton19" style="color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);" Text="BrixmorMSARank" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="BrixmorMSARank" /></th>
                                                <th runat="server"><asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkButton20" style="color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);" Text="Count" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="Count" /></th>
                                                <th runat="server"><asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkButton21" style="color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);" Text="Region" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="Region" /></th>
                                                <th runat="server"><asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkButton22" style="color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);" Text="DistancefromNewDev" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="DistancefromNewDev" /></th>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr runat="server" style="background-color: rgba(237, 45, 34, 1); color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); text-align: left;">
                                    <td runat="server">
                                        <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server">
                                            <Fields>
                                                <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowFirstPageButton="True" ShowLastPageButton="True" />
                                            </Fields>
                                        </asp:DataPager>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </LayoutTemplate>                        
                    </asp:ListView>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CnnStr %>" DeleteCommand="CompDev_Delete" DeleteCommandType="StoredProcedure" InsertCommand="CompDev_Insert" InsertCommandType="StoredProcedure" SelectCommand="CompDev_Select" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" UpdateCommand="CompDev_Update" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">
                        <DeleteParameters>
                            <asp:Parameter Name="CompID" Type="Int32" />
                        </DeleteParameters>
                        <InsertParameters>
                            <asp:Parameter Name="NewDevCount" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="DevelopmentName" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="City" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="State" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="ZipCodeofNewDev" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="ProjectStatus" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="ShoppingCenter" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="ProjectStartDate" Type="Double" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="ProjectDescription" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="ProposedAnchorTenants" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="GLA" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="EstCompDate" Type="Double" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="Developer" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="BusinessUnit" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="BU" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="CenterName" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="MSA" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="BrixmorMSARank" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="Count" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="Region" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="DistancefromNewDev" Type="String" />
                        </InsertParameters>
                        <UpdateParameters>
                            <asp:Parameter Name="CompID" Type="Int32" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="NewDevCount" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="DevelopmentName" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="City" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="State" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="ZipCodeofNewDev" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="ProjectStatus" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="ShoppingCenter" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="ProjectStartDate" Type="Double" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="ProjectDescription" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="ProposedAnchorTenants" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="GLA" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="EstCompDate" Type="Double" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="Developer" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="BusinessUnit" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="BU" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="CenterName" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="MSA" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="BrixmorMSARank" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="Count" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="Region" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="DistancefromNewDev" Type="String" />
                        </UpdateParameters>
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

So - what I did:
I set up a simple listview, hooked to the connection string in the web.config. The listview has a SQL Data Source hooked to that connection string, and it uses the stored procedures above for its data CRUD operations. I even added in your styles so the LV looks like your GV looked.

I'm ok with it if you don't accept this as your answer, since I didn't technically fix your gridview issues, instead replacing them. That said, using this solution would make your work move right along. :)

Comment: Thanks PKD.  This was right on of what I was trying to do.  The Gridview definitely has some issues but the ListView seems to be the better solution as what I am trying to do here.  Thanks again.

Comment: ListViews are wonderful things. A GridView has its place, but data editing works better in the ListView, I've found. Less requirement for custom coding and such. 

You can also add in your AJAX validators and ASP validators in the listview pretty easily. 

Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Noticed you are in fact pushing the Status value. There's a couple reasons it might not function:
1. The order in which you're calling the parameters is different than the order in which they are defined in the stored proc. Pass status last in your C# code. (in fact, double check all your parameters to make sure they're going in the same order as the proc)
2. The case on "status" is different in your stored proc vs your C# code. Make sure all your input parameters are identical in your C# code to the parameters in the proc.

The best thing to do, initially, is re-write your proc to do 1 thing  and do it well. Once that works, you can re-tool the proc to do more. Though, in line with MarcS, you really oughta refrain from multi-use procs, as maintenance and upkeep on them is a right pain.

Comment: Yeah - saw that when I gathered all the code into my editor. Try reorganizing the parameters in your C# to match the order in the Proc, for starters. Then also make sure the Case is the same in both. ("@status" vs "@Status").

Comment: I separated out the update to a new stored procedure and got rid of the status.  Please look above to my edit.  What am I doing wrong that the data will not update?

Comment: There are several things in this proc that I don't initially understand. You're using Floats to store dates. You're using unicode storage for everything else. You're using nchar(10) to store what should be an int ("Count").

A few suggestions: Store your dates as DateTime instead of Float. Drop all those unicode datatypes, unless you truly are using unicode data (replace nchar with char, nvarchar with varchar).

Comment: In addition to that, run SQL Profiler, and see what the call is that is running your SQL statement from the code. Copy that call from Profiler, and use it in SQL to see what the exact errors are.

Check to make sure you're passing the CompID validly. Step through your code in Debug to make sure all your datatypes are passing correctly.

Can you tell us what error you're seeing? (if any)

Comment: I'm setting up a micro project with your exact code with now, to test this out and get you an answer.

Comment: Well, try as I might, I couldn't get the gridview working right - editable gridviews have always been a sore spot with me. But, that said, I was able to get code working. It's in an answer below.

Comment: I'm sorry PKD but I do not see the answer below.  I am not sure what you are referring to.  Is there something that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

You pass the `Status=Update` and this force your stored procedure to run the Update part of your SP, but then you call the SqlDataAdapter.Fill method that is supposed to SELECT records to fill the dataset, but your procedure executes an UPDATE e no records are returned.

If you really want to execute this very non intuitive and (in my opinion) weak code, you need to move the select part at the end of the stored procedure and execute it in every case.

```
IF(@Status = 'Add')
BEGIN
   ....
END
ELSE IF(@Status = 'Update')
BEGIN
   ....
END
ELSE IF(@Status = 'Delete')
BEGIN
   ....
END
-- Always return the records after the update/insert/delete 
SELECT * FROM WestCompetition
```

However the above comment of [marc_s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13302/marc-s) has said everything, nothing to add at that

Comment: I separated out the update to a new stored procedure and got rid of the status.  Please look above to my edit.  What am I doing wrong that the data will not update?